# primeng p-sidebar - content text overlapping close icon

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-sidebar-demo-mznrgk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

As per the output of the above editor, is there any way I can avoid text overlapping over the close icon? I don't want to shift the text to the next line. From the developer tools, I came to know, the styling of the close button as `{position: absolute; top:0; right:0;}`

I tried using `word-wrap: break-word` but it didn't work.

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.p-sidebar-close {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

Override or change the CSS properties of `.p-sidebar-close` `position: relative;` and `float: right;`

Comment: changing the `width` or `margin` of the `div` will modify other lines, I want the below lines to be positioned to the end of the sidebar.

Comment: Accepted your answer, but somehow it's not working in my project. The close button,  after adding your change is now appearing one line above the div. I'm not able to reproduce in stackblitz.

Comment: I see your CSS file. Is your component connected to it? It does not appear to be.

Comment: In `app.component.ts` replace `styles` with `styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]`

Comment: That's fine, I validated it in developer tools.